# How to Disable a Button to be clicked many times in an Ajax Updatepanel?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have a `Label` a `Timer` a `Button` and a `RequiredFieldValidator` (to validate if `TextBox2.Text` were not empty) inside an `Updatepanel` in asp.net. The `TextBox2` is  outside of the `Updatepanel`. I want to send the `TextBox1.Text` one time to the `Label` and empty the `Textbox2.text` after clicking on the `Button`, But I dont know why when I click the Button many times( rapidly), it sends the `TextBox2.Text` in each click to the `Label` (Actually I need the TextBox2.Text paste just one time to the Label, after it I have used a code to erase the TextBox2 content and ready for the next TextBox2.Text. It works fine if I click one time and wait till the text to be pasted to the Label and then type some messages again and press the button) . The timer `Interval` is 2000. I use this code in the Button Click event:

```
  Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim lbl2 As String = Label2.Text
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Me.Page.[GetType](), "myScript", "document.getElementById('" + TextBox2.ClientID & "').value = '';", True)
    SetFocus(TextBox2)
    Label2.Text = lbl2 & TextBox2.Text
    Using w As New StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~/myfolder/1.txt"), True)
        w.Write(TextBox2.Text & "<br>")
    End Using
End Sub
```

Is there any idea to solve this problem? Is javascript code helpful?

Comment: can you show us the `page_load` code?

Comment: How may it influence this? Is there any way disable client press Enter or press the button before 2 seconds passed? When I disable the time everything works fine.

Comment: Actually why you need to do enabled = false, for blocking user from clicking again and again or something else

Comment: I don't need to disable it. I just tested it. After client pressed the  Enter Key or the Button I want the textbox.text to paste just one time on the lable. But it paste many times. Perhaps because Time event is in the middle of its work.

Comment: Uptdated the question

Comment: The Button1 is in an Ajax UpdatePanel, But TextBox2 is not. May that cause this Error?